# Can not select an item in an unbound combo box in access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have  form that is not based on any table and I have a combobox on it that gets it data from a query (which hs id and text).
When I look at form in formview, I can open the dropdown section of combobox and it has values from the query, but I am not able to selct it. I tried to select it by any of the following ways:

1- Clicking on an item.
2- DBClicking on an item
3- Pressing ener on an item.

What is the problen and how can I fix it?

I am using Accesss 2003 on windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you by accident set the *Locked* property to *Yes*? You can still drop down a locked combo-box but can't select any items.

Answer (score 0):

See if your Form has property Allow Edits set to True.